# Computation of the moment of order 3 of Gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

https://i.gyazo.com/9ab33847b7a2f8f7378f12e1ab5960b9.png

A continuous random variable $X$ has the $\mathsf{Gamma}(\alpha, \lambda)$ distribution with probability density
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\lambda x},
\text{ for } x > 0.$$
Prove from first principles that $E(X^3) = \frac{\alpha(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)}{\lambda^3}.$

I don't know what it means when it says from first principles. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the problem in the image directly into the problem. Please check that it is accurate. \\ I suppose you are asked to express $E(X^3)$ as an integral involving the density function and do the integration.

Comment: I have edited your title in order it reflects the content of the question

Comment: Note that $\int x^3 f_{\alpha} (x) dx$ is very similar  to $\int f_{\alpha +3}(x) dx $ if you adjust the constants at the front of $f$.

Comment: @user121049 So doing the integral in this situation means to do it from first principles? It was just that wording that was throwing me off. I did do the integral and found $$\int\limits_0^\infty(\lambda^{\alpha+3}x^{\alpha+2}e^{-\lambda{x}}/\Gamma(\alpha+3)) dx = 1$$ and so I ended up with $$E[X^{3}] = \Gamma(\alpha+3)/\lambda^3\Gamma(\alpha)$$ Is this valid and means I worked it out from first principle?

Comment: "First principles" is a bit open ended. How far back is one expected to go? I think your answer is good. I guess they just didn't want you to look the answer up in a book.

Comment: "From first principles" probably means something like "using only that each such function is a PDF" since this simple remark implies at once that, for every positive $\beta$, $$I(\beta)=\int_0^\infty x^{\beta-1}e^{-\lambda x}dx$$ has the value $$I(\beta)=\Gamma(\beta)\lambda^{-\beta}$$ A consequence is that, for every $k$, $$E(X^k)=\lambda^\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)^{-1}\int_0^\infty x^kx^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}dx=\lambda^\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)^{-1}I(k+\alpha)=\lambda^\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)^{-1}\Gamma(k+\alpha)\lambda^{-k-\alpha}=\ldots$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $$f(x)=\frac{\lambda^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-\lambda x},
\text{ for } x > 0$$
and
$$\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)=\lambda^{\alpha} \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = \lambda^{\alpha} \left( \left[ \frac{x^{\alpha} e^{-\lambda x}}{\alpha} \right]_0^{\infty} + \int_0^\infty \lambda \frac{x^{\alpha} e^{-\lambda x}}{\alpha}\,dx \right) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Gamma(\alpha+1,\lambda).$$

We see that $$E(X^3)=\int_0^{\infty} x^3 f(x)\,dx = \frac{\int_0^{\infty} \lambda^{\alpha} x^{\alpha+2} e^{-\lambda x}\,dx}{\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)}.$$

Note that $\int_0^{\infty} \lambda^{\alpha+3}x^{\alpha+2} e^{-\lambda x}\,dx = \Gamma(\alpha+3,\lambda)$ so our numerator is $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+3,\lambda)}{\lambda^3}$ and

$$E(X^3) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+3,\lambda)}{\lambda^3 \Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)} = \frac{\alpha(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{\lambda^3}.$$

QED.